# Background image is not displaying in IE6 and IE7

Tags: html, css

I  Have 3 divs 
HTML MARKUP

```
<div class="top-content-wrapper"></div>
<div id="content-wrapper">
</div>
<div class="bottom-content-wrapper">
</div>
```

Applied CSS on

```
.top-content-wrapper {
background:url("img/white-box-top-bg.gif") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
height:10px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0 30px;
width:686px;
}
#content-wrapper {
background:url("img/white-box-middle-bg.gif") repeat-y scroll left top transparent;
margin:0 auto;
padding:10px 25px 70px;
width:696px;
}
.bottom-content-wrapper  {
background:url("img/white-box-bottom-bg.gif") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
height:53px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0 30px;
width:686px;
}
```

In all major browsers its working fine but in IE6 and iE7 the background is not displaying please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Is there actual content within the divs? Try putting something in there like &nbsp;

Comment: @Sam that could actually be it - why not make it an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure, but it *may* be that you have a wrong order of parameters for the backgrounds. The proper way to sort them is this one:

`background: transparent url("img/white-box-middle-bg.gif") repeat-y scroll left top;`

Also, as Sam152 said in the comments, it may be the case that you don't have content in your divs, so they won't show in some browsers at all.

Comment: It's either this or the missing content in the div's as Sam points out. Even if it is not the reason for the problem at hand, stuff like this is why I really, really am against shorthand notation. Writing out every value properly and in full is *so* much better and clearer when it comes to debugging.

Comment: Hey thanks its working yes its because of wrong order of parameters.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Don't forget to mark this answer as correct then, so others seeing this problem in the future know how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers (IE generally) don't like it when you have empty divs or divs with only whitespace in them. Generally it's better to chuck in a [non-breaking space](http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/non-breaking-space.htm) (`&nbsp;`) character to make sure that the browser actually thinks it's worth displaying.