# Background image not displaying on IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

My footer has a repeating background image. It shows up perfectly on modern browsers. Here is what it looks like on Firefox.

[image: On Firefox]

But then when viewing it on Internet Explorer 7

[image: Internet Explorer 7]

Here is my code that controls the background.

**CSS**

```
#footer {
  background: transparent url("/assets/img/template/wild_oliva_dark.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
#footer {
  text-align: left;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
```

It is not in a media query.

As you can see, I used a `<div>` with id of `#footer` instead of using `<footer>` for better compatibility with older browsers. I am using [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

**EDIT:**
At the suggestion of another member, I added Selectivizr. But I might have implemented it wrong because it did not test out successfully.

[image: after test]

**EDIT 2:**
The footer is using responsive sticky footer styling. Not sure if some of those classes are affecting it.

```
<div id="footer" class="block">
```

The `block` class has this:

```
.block { display: table-row; height: 1px; }
```

Comment: You still need compatibility with IE7??

Comment: Try to separate all properties to their own rules.

Comment: @donfuxx yeah well our audience is that -1% percent that uses IE7 lol. Mostly dental labs, medical establishments don't upgrade that often. Our analytics showed about 40% users using IE7 :(

Comment: 40% of IE users or 40% of all users? Anyhow in both cases it is a really high percentage of IE7 users :-/ Good Luck!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background image is not displaying in IE6 and IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881637/background-image-is-not-displaying-in-ie6-and-ie7)

Comment: @cimmanon, yeah I thought that similar question would answer was similar but the accepted answer did not work.

Comment: @cimmanon, can you do me a favor and remove your close vote because the question is not similar. That person has no content in his divs and the answer said "don't have content in your divs, so they won't show in some browsers at all." And also the other part of the answer mentioned the wrong order or rules, which I fixed and tested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your shorthand of background is in the wrong order.

Try

```
background: transparent url("/assets/img/template/wild_oliva_dark.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
```

Comment: Thank you. Just tried it but still not displaying. will update my question with new css.

Comment: You really need to have this repeated background?

From this pic I see just a black background.

Anyway, when you try to put a solid color on it what happens?

Comment: yes the image actually is a small pattern that is repeated. I actually did try to give it a `background-color: #1a1a1a` as a fallback but that did not work unfortunately. It is fine on IE8 though.

Comment: Does the #footer width and height set?

Put the code on [link](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the footer. No they are not fixed heights or widths.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use  [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) for your css file.

The selectivizr similar modernizr.

selectivizr is a JavaScript utility that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6-8. Simply include the script in your pages and selectivizr will do the rest.

.

Step-By-Step using selectivizr

1-downloading [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/)

2-insert below code in the header.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[JS library]"></script>
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="[fallback css]" /></noscript>
<![endif]-->
```

3-Now you can use css3

Compatibility Ie 6 ,7,8

Comment: I think that your suggestion SHOULD work. But it did not, but perhaps I am making a mistake in its implementation. I updated the question with details.